# How to get the value of an array using the value from primary key

Tags: php, html

I am using the primary key of the room_extras table to create a unique name for my extra text field.

Here's the example:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $extrasInfo['description'] ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $extrasInfo['re_id'] ?>]" id="qty" value="0" style="text-align: right" size="5" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
    </td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($extrasInfo['price'],2) ?></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the name is generated using this code `extra[<?php echo $extrasInfo['re_id'] ?>]`.

The result of this in html is:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><h3>Economy Room</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Extra Person</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="extra[19]" id="qty" value="1" style="text-align: right" size="5" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
    <td align="right">560.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Breakfast for Extra Person</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="extra[20]" id="qty" value="1" style="text-align: right" size="5" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
    <td align="right">150.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><h3>Deluxe</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Extra Person</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="extra[1]" id="qty" value="0" style="text-align: right" size="5" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
    <td align="right">730.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Breakfast for Extra Person</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="extra[2]" id="qty" value="0" style="text-align: right" size="5" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
    <td align="right">269.00</td>
</tr>
```

Depending on the value of `re_id` field (i.e. `$extrasInfo['re_id']`) the array return a different key like:

```
extra[19]
extra[20]
extra[1]
extra[2]
```

So my question is how do I get the value after "extra"? That is, the numbers 19, 20, 1, and 2.

Here's what I have started:

```
$size = count($_POST['extra']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $qty = $_POST['extra'][$i];
    $re_id = ????; //what should be the code here?

    $query = "$sql_extras="INSERT INTO `lf_bookings_extras`(`re_id`, `booking_number`, `price`, `qty`, `amount`) VALUES ('$re_id','$booking_number','$price','$qty','$amount')";";

    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");

    ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not name your `extra` array from form input, that way you can loop in that array.

```
$re_id = $_POST['extra'][$i];
```

and HTML

```
<input type="text" name="extra[]" id="qty" value="1" style="text-align: right" size="5" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

or if you really want to do that

```
foreach($_POST['extra'] as $key => $val){
    $qty = $val;
    $re_id = $key;
    // $key will be the id passed from input
    // mysql insert
}
```

PS: please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: hi, i think you don't understand my question. in the html output above i have different room type like Economy Room and Deluxe. Each room type has an extras like "Extra Person" and "Breakfast for Extra Person". So I need the value of each extras according to its primary key. that is an extra of deluxe has different value from the extra of Economy Room.

Comment: in short i need to pass the value of `$extrasInfo['re_id']`